# Billboard sign electrical problem

Tags: dc-motor, dpdt

I am building a billboard with a moving part. The movement is an ore cart, rolling on a track. I have installed a chain loop below the cart to move it from one end of the sign to the other, then back again. It takes about 40 seconds to travel the 30 feet across the sign.

Problem: How do I get the reversible DC motor to switch directions as the cart nears the end of the track and make it cycle back?

I have plenty of 12v power, solar and stored. The motor has two leads, and is reversible, so all I need to do is to figure out how to reverse the polarity each time the cart nears an end of the track.

I'm thinking DPDT timer, set to change every 40 seconds, fine-tuned to how long it actually takes to traverse the track.

Comment: Why not use limit switches and a relay? Should be a pretty simple circuit... The issue with timers is that it will change if your system has any issues or if you get the timing even slightly wrong.

Comment: Limit switches plus an H bridge or something? I'd imagine that would work

Comment: How thick is your chain? Will the jerk break it?

Comment: How heavy is it?  You ought to think about coasting or braking to a stop before full voltage reversing or use PWM soft reverse.

Comment: Is this a toy cart or how much mass it being pulled? Current tot start?

Comment: use a mechanical linkage that can follow both sides of the chain.

Answer (score 1):

An ore cart is not a toy , I suspect.  So there must be some large motor needing 100A or so to change directions.

[image]

You need to sense the cart for a stretch to stop at each end and during which the velocity ramp is reduced to zero at a rate the motor can handle. Then toggle the reverse switch and ramp up at the same rate as braking.  So there is still a bunch of work to create the cart sensors, create a ramp voltage compare to zero and toggle the direction relay.

Let the 100A or so Motor speed control do the PWM for you.
[image]

### Design considerations.

- Acceleration forces on chain and battery power consumption changing directions per cycle per hour.
- Thermal stress on reverse acceleration
- sensor reliability
- failsafe endstop.

Can you consider a massive end-spring to return energy back to the cart and save battery power?

Comment: You really don't need to reverse direction on the motor at all if you set up the mechanism correctly. The top side of the chain moves one way, the bottom side moves the other and reverses gently at either end. Just need something attached that follows with the chain.

Comment: That’s what I thought originally but I may have overestimate the mass.  Starting and stopping at full voltage cause 20x the max rated motor current initially is not so efficient as continuous with a smooth large cycle to change motion velocity will still loses energy but can be more gentle on current and jerk stress.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, using a magnetic latch relay and limit switches at the start and at the end of the track.

[image]

Comment: Massive reverse surge currents and contractor arcing

Comment: not to mention the jerk on the gear & chain !

Comment: Hi Tony, It's presumed that it's just a model of an ore cart on the billboard!